# SQL best alternative to a LEFT JOIN and WHERE statement?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Basically I have two tables.  Customer and Purchase table. My Problem is the Purchase Table is very large and causing performance issues, and I'm trying to keep my code organized into relevant CTE's.

I'm trying to pull all the purchase records for those who purchased a Guitar Type A or have no purchases.

I want to filter out any customer who didn't buy a GuitarType A **but still keep customer who didn't buy anything.**

Here's my code:

```
WITH Purchases AS 
(
    SELECT
        , CustID
        , GuitarType
    FROM
        Purchase
    WHERE
        GuitarType = 'A'
)
,
RelevantCustomers AS
(
    SELECT
        P.Custid
        , P.PurchaseDate
        , C.CustType
    FROM
        Customer

)
SELECT
    Custid
    , GuitarType
    , PurchaseDate
FROM
    Purchases AS p
INNER JOIN
    RelevantCustomers AS rc ON p.CustId= rc.CustId
```

Customer:

```
  +--------+-------------+----------+
    | CustId | CreatedDate | CustType |
    +--------+-------------+----------+
    | 1      | 01/01/2017  | A        |
    +--------+-------------+----------+
    | 2      | 01/01/2018  | B        |
    +--------+-------------+----------+
    | 4      | 01/01/2018  | C        |
    +--------+-------------+----------+
```

Purchase

```
+----------+--------------+------------+
| GuitarId | PurchaseDate | GuitarType |
+----------+--------------+------------+
| 1        | 04/01/2018   | A          |
+----------+--------------+------------+
| 1        | 05/01/2018   | A          |
+----------+--------------+------------+
| 1        | 06/01/2018   | C          |
+----------+--------------+------------+
| 2        | 06/01/2018   | A          |
+----------+--------------+------------+
| 2        | 06/01/2018   | B          |
+----------+--------------+------------+
| 2        | 06/01/2018   | A          |
+----------+--------------+------------+
```

If I use INNER JOIN  then it will only return those who bought Guitar Type A. If I use LEFT then it will include all Customers.

One alternative is to move the "Where GuitarType = 'A' down to the where clause and do a LEFT JOIN but this will cause my code to be unorganized and potentially some performance issues.

Comment: If your code is running really slow look at the structure and adding indexes without complicating what should be a simple query.  Even with millions of rows if designed properly it should not be an issue

Comment: Your "current code" would return an error since `P` isn't created in the FROM clause of your second CTE, but is referenced in the SELECT list.

Comment: @Sewder . . . Is it reasonable to assume that if a customer purchased something, then the `guitartype` is non-`NULL`?  And what does it mean to pull the purchase records for a customer who did not purchase anything?

Comment: I suggest you try to select purchases for GuitatType = 'A' and fetch customer info using sub-query and then union with all customers who have not purchased anything. Also I think having index on CustomerID in Purchase table is necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might do it

```
SELECT rc.Custid, p.GuitarType, p.PurchaseDate
  FROM RelevantCustomers rc 
  LEFT JOIN Purchases p 
    ON p.CustId = rc.CustId
  LEFT JOIN Purchases pn 
    ON pn.CustId = rc.CustId 
   AND p.GuitarType != 'A'
 WHERE (p.GuitarType = 'A' OR p.CustID IS NULL)  
   and  pn.CustID is null
```

Answer (score 1):

You appear to want:

```
SELECT rc.Custid, p.GuitarType, p.PurchaseDate
FROM RelevantCustomers rc LEFT JOIN
     Purchases p 
    ON p.CustId = rc.CustId
WHERE p.GuitarType = 'A' OR p.GuitarType IS NULL;
```

For performance, you want an index on `Purchases(CustId)`.

Comment: This won't work if it's possible for a purchase to have NULL for GuitarType.   What if somebody bought a cable?   OP's requirement:  "but still keep customer who didn't buy **anything**."